# Count total number of order item of each order in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table like below

```
|order_item_id|order_id|customer_id|
|     2       |   30   |    9      | 
|     3       |   30   |    9      | 
|     4       |   30   |    9      | 
|     5       |   30   |    9      | 
|     11      |   32   |    9      | 
|     12      |   32   |    9      | 
|     13      |   32   |    9      |
```

here i would like to count total number of order_item_id for each order_id using mysql.
please help

Comment: Is this homework? Posting homework is OK, but please tag accordingly. Also please post the query that you have tried and that did not work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select order_id, count(*) from t
group by order_id
```

**Edit:**

> yes this one i knew it, but actually i would like to list out all related records as well, not just count. – user804457

After the requirements changed, then this seems to be what you're looking for:

```
select * from t t1
join (
  select order_id, count(*) aCount from t
  group by order_id
) t2
on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```

Result:

```
+---------------+----------+-------------+--------+
| ORDER_ITEM_ID | ORDER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | ACOUNT |
+---------------+----------+-------------+--------+
|             2 |       30 |           9 |      4 |
|             3 |       30 |           9 |      4 |
|             4 |       30 |           9 |      4 |
|             5 |       30 |           9 |      4 |
|            11 |       32 |           9 |      3 |
|            12 |       32 |           9 |      3 |
|            13 |       32 |           9 |      3 |
+---------------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: yes this one i knew it, but actually i would like to list out all related records as well, not just count.

Comment: ok i apologies for that but now can you please give solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select order_item_id, count(order_id)
from orders
group by order_id
```

Comment: yes this one i knew it, but actually i would like to list out all related records as well, not just count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT order_item_id, COUNT(order_item_id) FROM your_table GROUP BY (order_id)
```

See the official documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: yes this one i knew it, but actually i would like to list out all related records as well, not just count.